# App Engine with JSON (Jersey)

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, jersey, gson

I am trying to produce JSON (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
If I am using MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, I am getting wrong output.
But whenever I am using text/plain I am getting the correct output.
I would like to work with MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON to set the correct headers.

Is this code correct ? (I am using Jersey + App engine)

```
@Path("all")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getAllPatients(){
    Patient x = new Patient();
    x.setNaam("david");
    String test = gson.toJson(x);
    return test;
}
```

This is the wrong output :

```
"{\"naam\":\"david\",\"leeftijd\":0}"
```

Edit :

It's working perfectly with XML (MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) but when trying with JSON I get the following error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.owlike.genson.reflect.BeanViewDescriptorProvider$BeanViewPropertyFactory.createAccessor(BeanViewDescriptorProvider.java:122)
at com.owlike.genson.reflect.BeanPropertyFactory$CompositeFactory.createAccessor(BeanPropertyFactory.java:49)
at com.owlike.genson.reflect.BaseBeanDescriptorProvider.provideMethodAccessors(BaseBeanDescriptorProvider.java:187)
at com.owlike.genson.reflect.BaseBeanDescriptorProvider.provideBeanPropertyAccessors(BaseBeanDescriptorProvider.java:94)
at com.owlike.genson.reflect.AbstractBeanDescriptorProvider.provide(AbstractBeanDescriptorProvider.java:106)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.BasicConvertersFactory.provide(BasicConvertersFactory.java:109)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.BasicConvertersFactory.create(BasicConvertersFactory.java:74)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.BasicConvertersFactory.create(BasicConvertersFactory.java:56)
at com.owlike.genson.reflect.AbstractBeanDescriptorProvider$ContextualFactoryDecorator.create(AbstractBeanDescriptorProvider.java:79)
at com.owlike.genson.reflect.AbstractBeanDescriptorProvider$ContextualFactoryDecorator.create(AbstractBeanDescriptorProvider.java:68)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:93)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:80)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:93)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:80)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:93)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.ChainedFactory.create(ChainedFactory.java:80)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.create(CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.java:58)
at com.owlike.genson.convert.CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.create(CircularClassReferenceConverterFactory.java:22)
at com.owlike.genson.Genson.provideConverter(Genson.java:196)
at com.owlike.genson.Genson.serialize(Genson.java:340)
at com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter.writeTo(GensonJsonConverter.java:91)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:289)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1029)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: try using genson 0.98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jersey can handle JSON on it's own, just set proper library dependencies: `jersey-json.jar`. See this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/).

In this case you'd directly return `Patient` and Jersey would handle the rest:

```
@Path("all")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Patient getAllPatients(){
    Patient x = new Patient();
    x.setNaam("david");
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without Maven ? I tried downloading the maven app engine plugin and adding the dependecies in the pom file and referencing the project in my app engine project but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sure, just add this library to your project.

Comment: How do I do this ? I tried builth path -> add libraries but the only option where I can select the plugin (library) is android classpath container ? Any ideas ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to use json from json.org.  I switched to the jar from source forge http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/ , which includes net.sf.json.JSONObject, and it works.  Not sure why the version from json.org doesn't work.  I plan on looking into it further, as I was asked to utilize with the standard implementation.  I am also using genson-0.97.jar.

Update:
Using json.org, just return it as a String.class and it works to populate the JSONObject.

For a single return value:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.readEntity(String.class));
```

For an array of values:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.readEntity(String.class));
```

The client can also receive it as type HashMap.class:

```
HashMap<String,String> resultsMap = response.readEntity(HashMap.class);
```

The service actually receives the parameters as a HashMap:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getServiceMethod(HashMap<String,String> requestAttributes) {
    ...
    Response finalResponse = Response.ok(somePojoCollection, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    return finalResponse;
}
```

Full client example:

```
private JSONObject executeService(AuthRequest inputAttributes) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080").path(
        "TestRestService2/rest/GetTestService");
    Entity<AuthRequest> entity = Entity.entity(inputAttributes,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Builder request = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response response = request.buildPost(entity).invoke();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.readEntity(String.class));
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(0);
    return json;
}
```

One can also pass a JSONObject through the client, but if using json.org, then use the toString()

```
JSONObject inputAttributes = new JSONObject(myHashMap);
Entity<String> entity = Entity.entity(inputAttributes.toString(),
                       MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the serialization by hand let Jersey handle it. Change your method to return Patient instead of String and thats all. You shouldn't have the surrounding quotes anymore.